# How to set the Navigation bar's Drop down Lists' Clicked-Button color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Sorry to bother But I have 2 Questions:

**1)** I have this sample website I'm designing these days. I have this little problem. When I click on the Dropdown list button (`Our Softwares`) everything works fine except its `Color`.  When I click on it for the drop down list, I need it's color to be changed to `green` but instead it shows a color resemblance to something `white` and it looks clumsy with the theme I'm applying to the site.

**Here's a screenshot of the site with clicked dropdown list**
[image]
This is the code snippet I'm using:

```
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#" style="color:white;">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" style="color:white;" onMouseOver="this.style.color = '#37b725'"
                           onMouseOut="this.style.color = '#ffffff'">About Us</a></li>

                    <li class="dropdown" >
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="color:white;" >Our Softwares<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Software 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Software 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Software 3</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

I even checked this button's `active` state and it didn't work:
Since  it is under the class `toggle-dropdown`, **I use this css part, but it didn't work:**

```
.btn-group .dropdown-toggle:active,
.btn-group.open .dropdown-toggle {
    outline: 0;
    background-color:red;
}

.btn-default:active:hover,
.btn-default.active:hover,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-default:hover,
.btn-default:active:focus,
.btn-default.active:focus,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-default:focus,
.btn-default:active.focus,
.btn-default.active.focus,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-default.focus {
    color: #333;
    background-color: red;
    border-color: #8c8c8c;
}
```

Here's the second question

**2)** I have created these thumbnails to be arranged like a photo gallery.

Here's the screenshot of them:[image]
When I arrange them like `horizontally` or `vertically`, there is this big space lying down **beneath them/site*. Actually the site is expanding Vertically the every time I insert a thumbnail horizontally/vertically.

I have attached a screenshot below:
[image]
And every time I add a thumbnail **it keeps expanding vertically** like the site has something deep below.

**Here's the code I'm using to align those thumbnails:**

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="photos/square.png" alt="Photo not found!">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3 style="font-size:16px;position:relative;left:35px;top:-27px;font-family:Myriad Pro;color:white;">Software Name</h3>
                    <p>...</p>
                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-ok" role="button">Read More</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="thumbnail" style="left:290px;top: -320px;">
        <img src="photos/square.png" alt="Photo not found!">
        <div class="caption">
            <h3 style="font-size:16px;position:relative;left:35px;top:-27px;font-family:Myriad Pro;color:white;">Software Name</h3>
            <p>...</p>
            <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-ok" role="button">Read More</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="thumbnail" style="left: 560px;top: -640px;">
        <img src="photos/square.png" alt="Photo not found!">
        <div class="caption">
            <h3 style="font-size:16px;position:relative;left:35px;top:-27px;font-family:Myriad Pro;color:white;">Software Name</h3>
            <p>...</p>
            <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-ok" role="button">Read More</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail" style="position: relative;left:5px;top: -640px;">
                <img src="photos/square.png" alt="Photo not found!">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3 style="font-size:16px;position:relative;left:35px;top:-27px;font-family:Myriad Pro;color:white;">Software Name</h3>
                    <p>...</p>
                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-ok" role="button">Read More</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="thumbnail" style="position: relative;left:290.5px;top: -960px;">
        <img src="photos/square.png" alt="Photo not found!">
        <div class="caption">
            <h3 style="font-size:16px;position:relative;left:35px;top:-27px;font-family:Myriad Pro;color:white;">Software Name</h3>
            <p>...</p>
            <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-ok" role="button">Read More</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**And Here's the `css` part handling these thumbnails:**

```
.col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, .col-lg-1, .col-xs-2, .col-sm-2, .col-md-2, .col-lg-2, .col-xs-3, .col-sm-3, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3, .col-xs-4, .col-sm-4, .col-md-4, .col-lg-4, .col-xs-5, .col-sm-5, .col-md-5, .col-lg-5, .col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6, .col-xs-7, .col-sm-7, .col-md-7, .col-lg-7, .col-xs-8, .col-sm-8, .col-md-8, .col-lg-8, .col-xs-9, .col-sm-9, .col-md-9, .col-lg-9, .col-xs-10, .col-sm-10, .col-md-10, .col-lg-10, .col-xs-11, .col-sm-11, .col-md-11, .col-lg-11, .col-xs-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12, .col-lg-12 {
        position: relative;
        min-height: 1px;
        padding-right: 15px;
        padding-left: 15px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-left: 0px; /*this will set the position of the thumbnail in the screen*/
    }
.row {
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px; /*this will stop the page giving a horizontal bar even if the whole page fits in screen perfectly*/
}


.thumbnail {
    display: block;
    padding: 4px 4px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    line-height: 1;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 300px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    position: relative;
    left: 5px;
    top: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: border .2s ease-in-out; /*this whole section is responsible for thumbnail-related tasks*/
    -o-transition: border .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: border .2s ease-in-out;
}

.thumbnail .caption {
    padding: 28px;
    color: #333;
    position: relative;
    top: -15%; /*this part handles the Software Name position and its related attributes*/
}
```

**I'm really sorry to bother you, but this keeps me bugging. I tried many times and I couldn't catch the problem**

Can anyone please tell me  where I have gone wrong???

Comment: Please narrow this down to a single question, and the navbar doesn't look like a Bootstrap 4 navbar. Are you sure you're using v4?

Answer (score 0):

hi add this to change dropdown color

```
.dropdown.open a
{
background-color:red;
}
```

hope this works...

Comment: No Sir, this is for the drop down list. I need to change the background color of `Our Software` button.

Answer (score 0):

**For your first question:**
You need to locate the css properties handling the links in the navbar and edit like this:

```css
.navbar-nav > .open > a, .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover, .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
    color: #FFF !important;
    background-color: #1eb321; /* or whatever your green color code is */
}

.nav li a:hover, .nav li a:focus {
    outline: 0; 
}
```

and then also remove the `style` attribute in your HTML, leaving it to be like this:

```html
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Our Softwares<span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Software 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Software 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Software 3</a></li>

  </ul>
</li>
```

**For your second question:**
Try to modify the structure of your html, making sure each thumbnail occurrence has the grid template classes like this:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="photos/square.png" alt="Photo not found!">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3 style="font-size:16px;position:relative;left:35px;top:-27px;font-family:Myriad Pro;color:white;">Software Name</h3>
        <p>...</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-ok" role="button">Read More</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="photos/square.png" alt="Photo not found!">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3 style="font-size:16px;position:relative;left:35px;top:-27px;font-family:Myriad Pro;color:white;">Software Name</h3>
        <p>...</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-ok" role="button">Read More</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="photos/square.png" alt="Photo not found!">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3 style="font-size:16px;position:relative;left:35px;top:-27px;font-family:Myriad Pro;color:white;">Software Name</h3>
        <p>...</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-ok" role="button">Read More</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="photos/square.png" alt="Photo not found!">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3 style="font-size:16px;position:relative;left:35px;top:-27px;font-family:Myriad Pro;color:white;">Software Name</h3>
        <p>...</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-ok" role="button">Read More</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="photos/square.png" alt="Photo not found!">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3 style="font-size:16px;position:relative;left:35px;top:-27px;font-family:Myriad Pro;color:white;">Software Name</h3>
        <p>...</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-ok" role="button">Read More</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Also, a better suggestion If I were you, would be to use masonry grid library to arrange each thumbnail. Always works like a charm :) [Masonry Page Link](https://masonry.desandro.com/) .
They have a detailed description on how to use it in your project. cheers.